# "git update-index --skip-worktree" suddenly no longer working

Tags: git

I am using git `update-index --skip-worktree` on some files, so changes won't be tracked. But suddenly it no longer works.

Using `git ls-files -v | findstr "^S"` it shows the files.
But `git status` still shows them as untracked changes. Normally they would not be shown and not be part of untracked changes.

I tried using `git update-index --no-skip-worktree` to reset the files, and then redo it, but without success.

I have no idea what is broken or where to even look, or if there was an update to the logic in git and it is now working as intended somehow.

This is on `git version 2.29.2.windows.2`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To me, if I found myself using either `update-index` or`ls-files` , would be a red flag that I'm doing something not the way it was intended to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files in question were staged automatically when applied from a stash. That's why they were showing up. Unstaging the files fixed it.